# VS Code Regex find and replace with lowercase, use \l or \L if possible

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellij-15

Is there a way to do a find and replace (regex) all uppercase characters in the matching strings with lowercase ones? Preferably in VS Code or IntelliJ
I already have my regex ready.

Edit: To be clear I already know who to find the matches. But looking for that function to replace all uppercase matches with lowercase ones

Answer (score 77, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- Select `.*` button and enter your RegEx
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (Mac) to select all matched results
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (Mac)
- Choose `Transform to Lowercase`

If you want to modify only part of the matching text you have to do 1 step extra.

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in the Find dialog it selects the full matching text but you can't move the (multi) cursors and make a partial selection.

After entering the regex, VSC will show you which parts will match the find.

- **Click somewhere in the file**
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (Select All)

or

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (**in** the Find dialog)

Now you can move the (multi) cursors and make a partial selection and apply the needed transform.

Comment: @Mark I thought the focus had to be on the editor, but Shift+Ctrl+L also works from the search box. Always learn a new thing a day.

Comment: When I tried to use `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `L` I got this message: `The number of cursors has been limited to 10000.`

Comment: @zwl That is the limit that is hard coded in VSC, max 10000 multi cursors, then you have to do it in a few parts or write a Python/Node script that processes the file(s)

Answer (score 126):

There is support for the case modifiers `\L`, `\l`, `\U` and `\u` Find/Replace (from Build 1.47 for replacing strings in an editor, and from Build 1.49 it also works in the Find/Replace across the workspace (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/105101)).

So you just have to put the `\l` modifier in front of all your matched uppercase groups, like

`\l$1`  see [regex101 demo1](https://regex101.com/r/h3B9sz/2)

or just put the `\L` in front of it all, like `\L`(rest of replace here). see [regex1010 demo2](https://regex101.com/r/h3B9sz/3)

---

Note that these modifiers work a little differently than you might be used to.  For instance:

`(de)(pth)`  Search

`\U$1$2`     Replace

`DEPTH`  expected result

`DEpth`   vscode result

The case modifier only works on the **immediate** capture group.  **Not** until it encounters `\E` or the end of the replace string.

I assume for this same reason **`\E` isn't implemented** in vscode at all, as it would be irrelevant given that only the immediate capture group is modified.

So to get `DEPTH` as the result you should use `\U$1\U$2`.

> The modifiers can also be stacked - for example, `\u\u\u$1` will
> uppercase the first 3 characters of the group, or `\l\U$1` will
> lowercase the first character, and uppercase the rest.
>
> Currently, these are only supported in the editor's find widget, and
> not in "Find in Files".

- from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_47.md#case-changing-in-regex-replace and https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_49#_workbench.

Comment: As noted, delivered in [1.47](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_47#_editor)

Comment: Worth noting this is currently only available in "Find and replace" and not "Find in files"

Comment: @alastairtree It does work in a search across files.  What are you trying to do precisely?

Comment: @Mark thanks, realised it only works with $1+ and not $0 like in some other regex tools