# Regex in VSCode: case conversion in replace, modifiers \l, \L, \U, \u not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to replace a structure like this:

```
testVars.bread.componentFlour
testVars.bread.componentWater
```

to something like this:

```
testVars.dough.flour
testVars.dough.water
```

this happens with multiple variable names; I want to remove the component and have the first letter converted to lowercase to match CamelCase.

What I tried doing was matching `testVars.bread.component(.)` replacing it with `testVars.dough.\l$1`.

According to regex documentation, that should convert my match to lowercase. However, VSCode wants to insert `\l` as text.

How do I get VSCode to convert my match to lowercase?

EDIT: To clarify, this is strictly for VSCode's implementation, not a regex question itself. Matching this group in notepad++ and replacing with `testVars.dough.\l\1` does exactly what I want it to do.

Comment: I think VS Code uses $1 for back references

Comment: yes, using `testVars.dough.$1` to replace it works, but that leaves it in uppercase. What I want to do is convert to lowercase.

Comment: See Mark comment on this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59785124/9938317). VSC does not support `\l` or similar construct in Regex yet.

Comment: [Does now](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_47#_editor). `1.47` is out.

Answer (score 2):

NEW ANSWER: **!! Those case modifiers like \l and \u are being added** to the **find**/replace functionality in vscode (both in find within one file and search across multiple files [v1.49] - see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/105101) (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_47.md#case-changing-in-regex-replace) - will be in v1.47 (find) and v1.49 (search across files).

So that your original thought to

Find : `testVars.bread.component(.)`

Replace : `testVars.dough.\l$1`

is now working.

For more on how the case modifiers work in vscode, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62270300/836330

---

OLD ANSWER:

While you cannot replace with a lowercase identifier in vscode, you still have some of options.

1. Use a regex like `(?<=testVars\.).*\.component(.*)` so that `testVars.` is not captured - because you do not want to change its case.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select all your matches (same as`editor.action.selectHighlights`).
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, type `lower`and trigger that command (or make a keybinding for this unbound command).
4. Trigger your `replaceAll`

---

To speed that up you have two options.  (1) Make a macro that would run steps 2, 3 and 4. Or (2) make a snippet that will transform your selections - effectively running steps 3 and 4 at once.

Snippet in your keybindings.json (not in a snippets file):

```
{ 
  "key": "alt+m",                          // choose some keybinding
  "command":  "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/.*\\.component(.*)/dough.${1:/downcase}/}"
  },
},
```

and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select all, and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> to trigger the above `insertSnippet`.

[image: lowercase snippet]

---

**Macro approach:**

Using some macro extension, here [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), put this into your settings.json:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

  {
    "command": "multiCommand.findReplaceLowercase",
    "sequence": [
      "editor.action.selectHighlights", {
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": {
          "name": "replace and lowercase",
        }
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

and a snippet, in one of your snippets files:

```
"replace and lowercase": {   // this "label" is used in the macro
  "prefix": "for",
  "body": [
  
      "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/.*\\.component(.*)/dough.${1:/downcase}/}"
    
      // "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.*)/${1:/downcase}/}"  // to downcase all selected text
    
  ],
  "description": "replace selected text"
},
```

and a keybinding to trigger the macro:

```
{ 
  "key": "alt+m",        // choose some keybinding
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.findReplaceLowercase" },
}
```

[image: demo of lowercase macro]

---

In the demo I copy the find regex into the find widget (or just write it there, it doesn't matter how it gets there or where focus is) and then hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> (the macro keybinding) and that is it.

Obviously, this looks like a lot of work but you could keep **reusing the macro and snippet**, transforming to the replace result you would like the next time.  And there you can use `/downcase`, `/upcase`, `/capitalize` and `/pascalcase` all you want which you can't use in the replace field of the find/search widgets.