# Regex convert to uppercase in VSVim

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets, vsvim

I'm currently using `:s/(-[a-z].*-)([a-z])/$1\U$2/.`, however this just deletes the character after the 2nd `-` instead of converting it to an uppercase variant?

I have a CSS file and I have several entries in the form of,
`ql-font-timesnewroman`, `ql-font-arial`, `ql-font-geneva`, etc. 
I want to convert them to `ql-font-Timesnewroman`, `ql-font-Arial`, `ql-font-Geneva`, etc.

I am using VSVim with VSCode, and I am not sure which version of Regex it uses (but I believe it is the Javascript variant).

If I use the PHP variant, it works fine. (https://regex101.com/r/8aZI2m/1)

But if I use the Javascript variant, it just sticks a `U` into the result: `ql-font-Utimesnewroman`.

In VSCode, it goes a step further and just inserts `\U` instead. (`ql-font-\Utimesnewroman`).

If I change the regex to look more like, `:s/(-[a-z].*-)([a-z])/$1/\U$2/.`, it just goes ahead and erases the 2nd match instead of converting it to uppercase (`ql-font-imesnewroman`)

Is there any special syntax that VSVim / VSCode needs for its regex to match and replace with an uppercase correctly?

Comment: VSC uses the Javascript regex variant so no `\U`

Comment: Damn, I figured after looking around at the different versions. I was hoping it was different, since for whatever reason the site treats `/\U` as `\U`, but VSC would just delete the match instead. Is there an uppercase variant for javascript regex?

Comment: you should use the `{1:/upcase}` https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variable-transforms

Comment: Reading over that link and your suggestion, my regex should look like `:s/([a-z])/${1:/upcase}/.` if I wanted to turn the first alpha character encountered into uppercase, correct?
But when I use that, all it does is replace the first alpha character with `${1:`.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

vscode v1.47 is adding support for the find/replace case modifiers like `\u`, etc.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62270300/836330

In your case you could use this as the replace:

```
 $1\u$2   // \u as you are only capitalizing a single letter
```

[I am not familiar with VSVIM so tell us if `s/(-[a-z].*-)([a-z])/$1\u$2/.` works for you.]

---

Older Answer:

Try this keybinding in keybindings.json, which inserts a snippet so that you can use a transform:

```
 {
    "key": "alt+b",              // whatever keybinding you wish
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/-font-(\\w+)/-font-${1:/capitalize}/g}""
    },
  },
```

You select your text first and then trigger the snippet.

This will work for :

```
ql-font-timesnewroman
// unrelated text here can be selected to and it will be unaffected.**
ql-font-arial

ql-font-timesnewroman, ql-font-arial, ql-font-geneva  // all in one line
```

If your selection includes unrelated text, it will be unchanged UNLESS it matches the `-font-(\\w+)` regex used by the snippet - which seems generally unlikely.

If you have a lot of these in a file and you are uncomfortable selecting the whole file and applying this transform, then Find first with the `-font-(\w+)` regex (note no need to double-escape the `\w` in the Find widget but you must use `\\w` in a snippet!) and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will select all matches and then you can trigger the snippet.