# Replace to Lower Case is not working in VS Code's Search View

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

According to [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59785124/vs-code-regex-find-and-replace-with-lowercase-use-l-or-l-if-possible), accompanied by a link to a GitHub PR that has been merged and the version has been released, users should be able to replace the results in global find to lower case using Regex. However, this feature is not working for me, and I am using a much later version of VS Code (1.77.3) than this was released for ([1.47](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_47#_editor)).

You can see that "HI" is replaced with "\LHI".

Can someone please explain how to replace to lowercase? Note that I am not looking to use "Transform to Lowercase" command from the command palette, as that does not perform mass replace.

[image]

Comment: Replace in files feature does not use the same regex flavor as in the in-document S&R feature. So, use Notepad++ for this.

Answer (score 1):

That kind of a replacement, using `\L$0` doesn't work in the Search replace.  You could just wrap the whole thing in a capture group like

```
(\b(?:HI|HELLO)\b(?![A_Za-z]))
```

and then replace with `\L$1` and it works as you expect.  `$0` does work in the replace field just not together with `\L`, `\U`, `\l` or `\u`.

Comment: I am testing this exact same example provided here on Visual Studio, I still get \LHI

Comment: @maryhadalittlelamb  This answer is for Visual Studio Code.  It doesn't apply to Visual Studio.